# How to perform SUM operation in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

I have a table.

```
create table tblCartItem(
pkCartItemId int primary key identity,
CartId int not null,
ProductId int not null,
Quantity int not null,
Price nvarchar(15)
)
```

and I want to perform sum opeartion on that like as

```
Select SUM(Price) from tblCartItem where CartId='107'
```

and I am trying to following code but its not working

```
ObjTempCart.CartTotal = (from c in db.tblCartItems where c.CartId == cartId select c.Price).Sum();
```

Any one help me to do this using Entity Framework.
I am using MVC 4 Razor.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Oops, I think I saw it. Why `Price` is string (`nvarchar(15)`)?

Comment: my query of entity framework

Comment: is any way to cast Price and then caculate

Comment: I doubt your SQL query works. The EF query is also ok as soon as the `Price` column can be summed, which is not the case with your data.

Comment: No, EF does not support conversion from string.

Comment: you'll have to gather your entries from the database using .ToList() and convert in memory.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

May be You can use lambda Expression

```
var total=db.tblCartItems.Where(t=>t.CartId == cartId).Sum(i=>i.Price);
```

Comment: Can not implicitly convert to 'string' to 'decimal' because in database my Price column is in NVARCHAR, to I do var total = db.tblCartItems.Where(t => t.CartId == cartId).Sum(i => Convert.ToDecimal(i.Price));

Comment: but now, LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal ToDecimal(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: its fine, so what values you have in price column? you may specify select first before that like var total = db.tblCartItems.Where(t => t.CartId == cartId).Select(p=>CovertToDecial(p)).Sum(i => i);

Comment: same problem, LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal ToDecimal(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: This is the "right" answer in the sense that my google query unrelated to decimal/data types, just "how to do sum in linq" led me to this. 

Answer (score 3):

its working try this..

*use **Decimal.Parse** to convert price.*

```
ObjTempCart.CartTotal =  db.tblCartItems.Where(t=>t.CartId == cartId).Select(i=>Decimal.Parse(i.Price)).Sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

Decimal.parse not working, try Convert.toDouble

```
double total = _context.Projecao
      .Where(p => p.Id == idProj)
      .Select(i => Convert.ToDouble(i.ValorTotal)).Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have a solution of that but its not exactly from Entity Framework, But its working...

```
 private double CartItemTotalPrice(Int32 CartID)
        {
            List<string> pricelst = new List<string>();
            pricelst = (from c in db.tblCartItems where c.CartId == CartID select c.Price).ToList();

            double Total = 0;

            if (pricelst != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < pricelst.Count; i++)
                {
                    Total += Convert.ToDouble(pricelst[i]);
                }
            }

            return Total;
        }
```

Comment: With this solution you are getting all the information to the client and do the work in the client, so it could be a problem with the performance depending on some cases. But it works, sure.

Comment: Better to push this work onto the database side and just have it return the sum itself, not the entities.